# Users Logged Out Automatically from Connected App

Tags: connected-apps, authentication, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, authorization, refresh-token

We have connected iOS App which uses mobile SDK Version 7.2,when the iPad is idle and used back after sometime, users are getting logged out of the application. They been asked to login back to the app but in the past connected app has worked without authentication for days.

Note: Refresh token for the connected app is valid until is revoked.
Has anyone faced a problem like this before? If so is there any work around? or any solution to this problem.

Comment: I am also facing this same kind of issue in my iOS application. My application contains salesforce ios mobile SDK and for some users, the application is automatically getting logged out!

There is no logout functionality available in my application, so I am not hitting any logout function from the salesforce mobile SDK however, still for some of the users' application is getting logout and navigating users to the initial salesforce login screen.

So if anyone has any solution for it, it would be really very helpful.

Comment: Refresh token doesn't magically void the logout or idle timeout.  Please edit your question and provide a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)